# Word 2010 save as PDF/A results in "This file could not be found."

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2010

When I try to save a document as PDF/A (ISO 19005-1 compliant) in Word 2010, I get an error message:

> This file could not be found.
>
> <kbd>OK</kbd>   <kbd>Help</kbd>

It works fine when I don't check the PDF/A box.

Any ideas what's wrong?

Comment: Does it happen with every document? or just this one in particular? Fonts need to be embedded in PDF/A compliance. Perhaps your document uses a font that cannot be found.

Comment: @Adam: Yes, every document.

Comment: Sounds like a corrupted install. Perhaps a reinstall of Microsoft Office is the easy answer.

Comment: @Adam: Ugh... I wasn't looking for an 'easy' answer necessarily. :P